# Observable.zip with Observable.timer

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I'm trying to zip two observables, in this case a timer task and a actual task so that my subscriber only gets called when both tasks are done. I wanted to do this with `Observable.zip` but somehow this doesn't work and my `Observable.timer` does not call `onComplete()`. This means the subscriber never gets the result of both `Observables`.

When I change `zip` to `merge` all of a sudden the `Observable.timer` does call `onComplete()`, what am I missing here?

```
Observable<Long> delayObs = Observable.timer(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
Observable<Void> methodObs = method();

mSubscription = Observable.zip(delayObs, methodObs, (pLong, pVoid) -> pVoid)
                              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                              .subscribe(__ -> thisDoesntGetCalled(), throwable -> M2Log.e(LOG_TAG,
                                      "error", throwable));
```

The method:

```
private Observable<Void> method() {
    return Observable.defer(() -> {
        // some work
        return Observable.empty();
    });
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Zip combines values but your method()'s Observable doesn't emit anything, therefore zip decides it won't be able to ever combine anything and then completes.

Comment: Thanks! That actually makes sense. If you post this as an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip combines values but your method()'s Observable doesn't emit anything, therefore zip decides it won't be able to ever combine anything and then completes.

You could change method to this and now zip does call the function you provided:

```
private Observable<Integer> method() {
    return Observable.defer(() -> {
        // some work
        return Observable.just(1);
    });
}
```